# FB.login callback returns error (bug or misconfiguration?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

If user is authorized, this simply redirects him to a second page. If however, user is not authorized, this prompts authorization popup.

```
$('#ay-facebook-authorize').on('click', function(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            window.location = 'home';
        } else {
            FB.login({scope: ay.scope}, function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Regardless of whether user does not agree or agrees to authorize the app, the following error is produced.

```
a is not a function
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js
Line 23
```

Context:

```
...ver._xdNextHandler(FB.Auth.xdResponseWrapper(a,d,e),b,c,true);},xdResponseWrappe...
```

Since I am not getting this error on my other projects, I am wondering whether this can be misconfiguration or a Facebook bug?

Answer (score 0):

A second after a made a most, I realized that the order of parameters in FB.login is wrong. First comes the callback function, then the parameters.

Leaving this up, in case someone runs into the same issue.